# Converting for loops to while loops in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I am struggling to find an efficient way to convert these *for* loops to a working set of *while* loops. Any Suggestions? I am using 2.7

```
def printTTriangle(height):
 for row in range(1,height+1):
    # print row T's
    for col in range(1,row+1):
        print 'T', 
    print
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: why do you wants to convert into while? for are better than while

Comment: You can also use `*` on strings: `print 'T' * 4 # TTTT`

Comment: also you can use `xrange` instead of `range`, might be slightly more efficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's like this:

```
def printTTriangle(height):
    row = 1
    while row < height+1:
        col = 1
        while col < row+1:
            print 'T', 
            col += 1
        print
        row += 1
```

Here's how I did it. For example, let's convert this line:

```
for row in range(1, height+1):
```

First step: create an iteration variable and initialize it in the starting value of the range:

```
row = 1
```

Second step: transform the ending value of the range into the loop condition, and careful with the indexes:

```
while row < height+1:
```

Finally, don't forget to advance the loop incrementing the iteration variable:

```
row += 1
```

Putting it all together:

```
row = 1
while row < height+1:
    row += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it and just use one while loop:

```
def printTTriangle(height):
    row = 1
    while row <= height:
        print 'T '*row
        row += 1
```

AND if you are not obsessed with while loops, here is a one liner:

```
def printTTriangle(height):
    print "\n".join(['T '*row for row in range(1, height+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the inner loop with string multiplication operator (`*`) :

```
def printTTriangle(height):
 j = 1
 while j <= height:
     print 'T' * j + '\n '
     j += 1
```