# Converting a for loop to while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to convert a very basic statement, like this

```
for i in the_list:
    work.append(i)
    y = y[1:]
```

From a `for` loop, to a `while` loop. I use code like this a lot and have been trying to learn about different ways to write it, without a for loop.

Comment: While it would be fairly simple to do this, it wouldn't be a good use of a `while` loop. `for` looks much more appropriate.

Comment: This question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900624/converting-for-loops-to-while-loops-in-python

Comment: @unicornication: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be:

```
i, length = 0, len(the_list)
while i < length:
    work.append(i)
    y = y[1:]
    i += 1
```

Note: this is not recommended, the `for` loop would be considered more Pythonic - it is both shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the intention is to just remove the loop then, list comprehension is also a good option

```
work =[i for i in the_list]
```

Comment: List comprehension is also a loop.