# Converting for loops into while loop

Tags: python

```
for (length, freq) in word_list:
    print(freq_temp.format(length, freq))
print("\n Len  Freq Graph")
for (length, freq) in word_list:
    graph_template = "{:>4}{:>5}% {}"
    number_symbol = "=" * percentage_frequency(freq, new_list)
    print(graph_template.format(length, percentage_frequency(freq, new_list),number_symbol))
```

How would you convert these for loops into while loops?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it into a `while` loop? What's the issue you're running into using `for` loops?

Comment: What is a `while` loop is comparison to a `for` loop?

Comment: im just curious as to how you would do it. I have done other conversions but this one stumps me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting for loops to while loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900624/converting-for-loops-to-while-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the point of `for` and `while` loops, [this question does a good job of explaining it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920645).

Basically, a `for` loops iterate through the list and you can operate on the items as it does so.

In contrast, `while` loop is used to run until a condition is met, such as a flag being triggered.

The `for` loop:

```
mylist = ["this", "is", "a", "for", "loop"]
for element in mylist:
    print(element)
```

Returns:

```
this
is
a
while
loop
```

Where as this while loop:

```
count = 0
while count != 10:
    print(count)
    count += 1
print("count has reached 10")
```

Returns:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
count has reached 10
```

In summary, a `for` loop is used to iterate through an `array` or `generator` object, where as a `while` loop is used to run until a condition is met.