# Coverting for loop to a while loop Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert this for loop to a while loop but am struggling.  It should have the same output

```
low = 3
hi = 50
total = 0
for m in range (hi, low-1,-2):
      total = total + m
print("Total is", total)
```

Comment: With what exactly are you struggling? Where is the code you tried and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting for loops to while loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900624/converting-for-loops-to-while-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
low = 3
hi = 50
total = 0
m = hi
while m>low-1
   total = total + m
   m = m-2
print("Total is", total)
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. It is always helpful to provide commentary to your code, please consider editing your answer to explain what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```py
low = 3
hi = 50
total = 0

# summing every 2nd number from 50 down to 4, inclusive 
# (including hi=50, excluding low-1=2)
for m in range(hi, low-1,-2):
    print(m)
    total = total + m
print("Total is", total)

print("---")
total = 0
i = hi # set index to hi
while i >= low: # as long as index is greater than or equal to low,
    print(i)
    total += i
    i -= 2 # decrease index by 2
print("Total is", total)
```

If you compare the two codes, you will see that they are indeed equal.